# Get the value of a cell on a ASPXGridview based on the button click

Tags: vb.net, aspxgridview

I have a ASPXGridview with a button as the first column for each of the rows. When I click a button I want it to perform a callback which will get me the value of the cell next to the button click. I'm a bit stuck on this so any advise would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a call back function to get key field name from a row on selection changed. 
Then when I click on the button is gets the selected keys on the page.